# f951 internal compiler error in fortran/module.c

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

Has anyone ever encountered the problem as I cannot identify what the problem might be.

```
f951: internal compiler error: in read_module, 
at fortran/module.c:4940
```

Here are more details about the compiler output. I am using a development version of gfortran 5.0. Tne problem seems to be related to some problem with using modules.

```
/home/gcc-5-20150201/bin/gfortran -o build/libbehi      
/meid/meidvectors.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib 
-fdiagnostics-color -Wall libbehi/meid/meidvectors.f

/home/gcc-5-20150201/bin/gfortran -o build/libviki/wavgenr
/wave_sigint.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib 
-fdiagnostics-color -Wall libviki/wavgenr/wave_sigint.f

f951: internal compiler error: in read_module, at 
fortran/module.c:4940

0x66090b read_module
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/module.c:4940

0x66090b gfc_use_module
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/module.c:6768

0x661eb6 gfc_use_modules()
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/module.c:6892

0x66c599 use_modules
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:116

0x66f944 decode_statement
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:332

0x6713d0 next_free
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:1049

0x6713d0 next_statement
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:1283

0x671f4c parse_spec
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:3296

0x675964 parse_module
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:5151

0x675964 gfc_parse_file()
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/parse.c:5457

0x6b59d5 gfc_be_parse_file
../../gcc-5-20150201/gcc/fortran/f95-lang.c:228

Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
scons: *** [build/libviki/wavgenr/wave_sigint.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: It is a bug in the compiler. There might be a workaround available, but you must show the code and the command that you run when you got this error. Also, you must provide the details about your compiler (and its version).

Comment: You must find a small minimal example, which still causes the problem and report it to GCC developers. Without your code we can't do anything for you.

Comment: That's the biggest problem as it does not give any information on where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an internal compiler error or ICE and is a bug in the compiler. You should do what Vladimir says and find the smallest program that triggers this ICE and then report the bug to gcc.

> Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>
> Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
>   See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.

The linked webpage in your error will have instructions on how to provide a useful bug report and how to file it.  GCC isn't interested in bugs against snapshots so you'll want to test this against either the released version of gcc 5 (currently 5.1) or the development trunk (gcc 6).